# error trasfering php array to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, parameter-passing

I have this array:

```
$men['display']=array( 
                  "edit"        =>"1", 
                  "description" =>"2", 
                  "phone"       =>"3", 
                  "mail"        =>"4" 
                 );
```

I tried to transfer it to javascript by using:

`<?php $disArray = json_encode($men['display']);?>`

then, I sent it to javascript:

`<select id="selectBoxHere" onChange="loadInnerHTML('<?php $disArray ?>')";>`

For some reason, my javascript function 'loadInnerHTML' dosen't send my array to javascript.

Comment: what is loadInnerHTML?

Comment: You're sending a JSON string to `loadInnerHTML()`, not an array. Either remove the `''` around `<?php $disArray ?>` or parse the string into an array with `JSON.parse()` Also, you're not echoing the variable.

Comment: its a javascript function.
I'm trying to pass a php array to a different page using ajax.

Comment: You need to decode Json coming from php.

read : [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: @user976990 Uh, no. If you hand it to javascript right (see my answer below) you don't need to decode.

Comment: When i remove the '' around the php code i get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Answer (score 3):

You forget the `echo` statment.

And if you use single quotes, it makes this a string. For a javascript object you don't need the single quotes, `json_encode` will ensure it is javascript safe.

```
loadInnerHTML(<?php echo $disArray ?>)
```

I'd also recommend that you store this variable directly in javascript first, rather than passing it into a function. Otherwise you have to worry about double quotes inside double quotes, breaking your `<select>` tag.

```
var disArray = <?php echo $disArray ?>;
```

Then you can just use that variable.

```
loadInnerHTML(disArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Echoing an array in php will result in

```
var dis_array = Array
```

which js couldn't understand. Try:

```
var disArray = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode( $disArray  ) ?>' );
```